# How to call getVersionFileName() from AWSCodeDeployPublisher plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm running AWS CodeDeploy on Jenkins Pipeline using AWSCodeDeployPublisher plugin.

This is a snippet which works just fine.

```
stage('CodeDeploy') {
  step([
    $class: 'AWSCodeDeployPublisher',
    applicationName: codeDeployName,
    deploymentGroupName: codeDeployGroup,
    deploymentConfig: codeDeployConfig,
    region: codeDeployRegion,
    s3bucket: codeDeployBucket,
    s3prefix: codeDeployPrefix,
    subdirectory: '',
    includes: '**',
    excludes: '',
    deploymentMethod: 'deploy',
    pollingFreqSec: 10,
    pollingTimeoutSec: 3600,
    waitForCompletion: true,
    proxyHost: '',
    proxyPort: 0,
    versionFileName: '',
    deploymentGroupAppspec: false,
    iamRoleArn: codeDeployRole
  ])
}
```

In the logs I see something like this:

```
Zipping files into /tmp/#153-1840224459256520369.zip
Uploading zip to s3://bucket-name/#153-1840224459256520369.zip
```

Now, I was scratching my head and was trying to find a way to get S3 URI after CodeDeploy is complete to let's say to generate pre-signed URL, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have looked at the plugin documentation and have found that it has a [getVersionFileName()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/codedeploy/com/amazonaws/codedeploy/AWSCodeDeployPublisher.html#getVersionFileName--) method which I believe should give me that? But how can I call it to get it work?

Comment: Pipeline AWS Steps plugin has `s3PresignURL` method: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#s3presignurl-presign-file-in-s3

Comment: @MaratC and how would you call for that method if you'd use that plugin?